# ordered by child attribute, in polymorphic polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

i have the following models

```
class Airplane < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :airtags
  has_many :pictures, :through => :airtags
end

class Airtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :airable_type, :airable_id, :airplane_id
  belongs_to :airplane
  belongs_to :airable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picturable, :polymorphic => true

  has_many :airtags, :as => :airable,   :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :airplanes, :through => :airtags
end
```

in my airplane show, i want to list all pictures, ordered by their name.

Answer (score 0):

`@airplane.pictures.order(:name)`

Comment: gives me that error  Could not find the source association(s) :picture or :pictures in model Airtag. Try 'has_many :pictures, :through => :airtags, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :airplane or :airable?

Comment: if i edit it to:  has_many :pictures, :through => :airtags, :source => :airable            i get: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Airplane#pictures' on the polymorphic object 'Airable#airable'.